# How does an app Bundle handle Language changes?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I wrote a small demo app with multi-language support. Then I built an app bundle and uploaded it to the play store.

When I change language setting in the system setting, the play store will be triggered to download additional language pack for my app.

But the problem is, if my app is in the foreground before the download finish, the download will be stopped, and will not continue to download until I have a new download task for the play store, such as requesting a dynamic feature module, or changing the language setting once again...And also it seems that when the language pack is downloaded and installed successfully, my app will be killed automatically. This makes App Bundle very hard to use when switching language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the app is foreground when the download finishes, Play Store will not install the additional language, because that would kill the app. Instead, the installation will happen at some point later.

Comment: Yes you are right. This makes sense. Currently Google does not have a way for us to handle the language refresh by ourselves.

Comment: Now it is not necessary to have a restart of application; "Your app needs to enable the SplitCompat Library in order to immediately access code and resources from a downloaded module—that is, before an app restart." https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore